# A particular version of Gronwall's inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have this theorem (Gronwall's inequality):

Let $f$, $g$ and $h$ be continuous nonnegative functions defined for $t\ge t_0$. If$$f(t)\le h(t)+\int_{t_0}^{t}g(s)f(s)\,ds\>,$$then$$f(t)\le h(t)+\int_{t_0}^{t}g(s)h(s)e^{\int_s^tg(u)\,du}\,ds$$

> How do I prove another version of the theorem, letting $h(t)=k$ , where $k$ is any nonnegative constant, i.e If$$f(t)\le k+\int_{t_0}^{t}g(s)f(s)\,ds\>,$$then$$f(t)\le ke^{\int_{t_0}^tg(s)\,ds}\,ds$$

I worked out the following
\begin{align}
f(t)&\le k+\int_{t_0}^{t}g(s)ke^{\int_s^tg(u)\,du}\,ds\\\\&=k\left(1+\int_{t_0}^{t}g(s)e^{\int_s^tg(u)\,du}\,ds\right)
\end{align}
How should I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Let $w(t)=v(t)\cdot\exp \left(- \int_{t_0}^{t}g(s)\mathrm{d}s\right)$

We have: $w'(t)<0, \forall t \ge t_0 \ge 0$, where $v(t)=k+\int_{t_0}^{t}g(s)f(s)\,\mathrm{d}s$.

Whence $w(t) \le w(t_0), \forall t \ge t_0 \ge 0$